# Visual Studio makes my projects be Java when I create a C++ Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

As you can see in the image below, I created a project under Visual C++ but as soon as I open the project template it is in Java. Cant this be fixed?

[image]

Comment: removing java tag.

Answer (score 3):

Choose `Native-Activity Application` if you want to write C++.